# tikz-qtree is all messed up

Tags: tikz-qtree, hebrew

I'm new to latex and I'm using Lyx to write my documents. Recently I needed to add binary trees to my document, and after some googling I found I could add the `tikz-qtree` package in order to draw them.
**At first It worked fine** but now it's all messed up and I don't have a clue why

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.1 2 3 ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this:
[image: messed up qtree]
Needless to say more complicated trees are worse by far...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you add a full MWE. That increases the chance that somebody else can reproduce your "error".

Comment: @StefanPinnow As said, I'm new to latex and I have no idea what "MWE" is or how can I add it. Would happily do so if explained how :)

Comment: @TzahMama See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: The MWE in your case would be `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \Tree [.1 2 3 ]
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}` which compiles fine. Now try to reduce your main document down to that code and somewhere you will find the culprit line. Should be something you added short time ago as it "worked fine" some time ago.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Took me some time to figure it out but I got the Latex code out of Lyx and managed to compile it. I've edited the question adding the MWE that I could compile. Trying writing down what you wrote worked fine. I'm guessing it's the interaction between tikz and babel maybe?

Comment: That is a real MWE. Thanks. But unfortunately I am not able to compile your code as it tries to load Hebrew fonts. I guess that this problem does go away, if you kick out Hebrew. For now I can just recommend to type this diagram in a separate file in pure English or to maybe have a look on `forest` (which might work, I don't know). If those solutions are not feasible for you, we have to wait until someone with more Hebrew knowledge passes by.

Comment: Also, just in case, try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. You could also try switching to English (LTR typesetting) before drawing the tree, if that's an option. I have no idea if Forest would fare better as it is still based on TikZ. `qtree` is *not* TikZ based and would be worth trying if your trees are relatively simple (and of the linguistic kind - it is not fun for logic).